# How to get client's detail in Node backend?

Tags: node.js, express

I designed backend for mobile application so user-agent does not include information which I need.
I am getting this information in my request header
[image]

I needed which OS is client using like (Android or  Ios),

also which Version is client using like (Android 10 or 11)

can I parse this information in backend ?

thanks in advance for answers.

Answer (score 0):

If your backend is some HTTP server, you could read information from the `User-Agent` HTTP header, but keep in might that this is not guaranteed to be correct.

Comment: user-Agent does not show proper informations.

Comment: @mohitbaraiya that's all you'll likely get.

Comment: I edit my  question and mention what I am  getting in header.

Comment: @mohitbaraiya, so some clients will set the header to something else, just like "OkHttp" did here. This is all you'll get on the server-side. If it's not in this header, its not  there. The client decides what's sent.

Comment: User-agent is still the answer unless you want to use some fingerprinting script in the front-end. Note though that fingerprinting falls into the category of encroaching on the user's privacy

Comment: At least "okhttp" appears to be an android client, so you'll know at least 1 thing.

Comment: ok thanks for sugeggetion @slebetman but without fingerprinting I can get this software info ?

Comment: @mohitbaraiya why do you keep asking the same thing after getting the answer?